# Can gradle tasks be created that subset the tests in a project?

Tags: testing, gradle

I am using the gradle tooling api to kick off tests based on receiving a webhook.

I don't see a way to pass parameters to the tooling API.  I can run tests with something like:

```
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector()
                .forProjectDirectory(new File(workingDir))
                .connect();
        try {
            connection.newBuild().forTasks("test").run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
```

But I don't see a way to run something like "gradle test --tests=xxx" so I was hoping I could make gradle tasks that were subsets of tests like "gradle dev_tests", "gradle int_tests".

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the gradle docs, newBuild() functions, conveniently ,as a builder pattern.
You can set several parameters before calling run() on it .

```
//select tasks to run:
    build.forTasks( "test");

    //include some build arguments:
    build.withArguments("--tests=xxx");
    ...
    build.run();
```

Source:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/BuildLauncher.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately I am getting an error with that approach:
build.withArguments("--tests=sometest");
org.gradle.tooling.exceptions.UnsupportedBuildArgumentException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.1-bin.zip'.
Problem with provided build arguments: [--tests=somtest]. 
Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
Either it is not a valid build option or it is not supported in the target Gradle version.
Not all of the Gradle command line options are supported build arguments.
....

Comment: There is, however a TestLauncher that seems to work:  http://www.appsinventive.com/appsbuilder/var/apps/ionic/tools/gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.13-all/7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q/gradle-2.13/docs/groovydoc/org/gradle/tooling/TestLauncher.html